Prevent & to &amp; Translation in Ansible community.general.xml
I am using Ansible's community.general.xml to modify a file. I want to set the following
<Connector relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"/>

The Ansible code I am using is
- name: "Update relaxedQueryChars"
  community.general.xml:
    path: "/conf/server.xml"
    xpath: /Server/Service/Connector
    attribute: "relaxedQueryChars"
    value: "[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;"

In my file, the ampersands are being translated into &amp; and I am getting the following result
<Connector relaxedQueryChars="[]|{}^&amp;#x5c;&amp;#x60;&amp;quot;&amp;lt;&amp;gt;"/>

I have tried some of the following to prevent translation (none have worked)
value: '[]|{}^&#x5c;&#x60;&quot;&lt;&gt;'
value: "[]|{}^\&#x5c;\&#x60;\&quot;\&lt;\&gt;"
value: []|{}^\&#x5c;\&#x60;\&quot;\&lt;\&gt;

How can I prevent the translation of HTML entities within Ansible?

Did you tried plain characters? value: "[]|{}^\'<>"`. Seems ansible would escape them.

Interestingly, Ansible does escape some of them. "[]|{}^\\'<>"gets translated to"[]|{}^\&quot;&lt;&gt;". Hmmm... This gets more complicated.

Probably it escapes only the xml reserved ones and there's no need to escape the others-

It seems to be related to XML and the Python implementations, see Preserving special characters in text nodes using Python lxml module, Is there a way to create an XML element in Python with special characters in its string? and many more ...
